# Chain rule problem (calc 3)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Could someone please explain what type of problem this is? I can't seem to find any good examples anywhere. I know it's a chain rule problem, but almost all examples i find is something like: find $
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ of some given function.

And it doesnt look like a typical differential equation problem either. Our teacher said it should be solved using the chain rule

---

Find the solution to: $y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} + x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = xyf(x,y)$

That satisfies $f(0,y)=y^2$

Use:

$u = ax^2+y^2$

$v = e^{-1/2x^2}$

---

Im hard stuck with this problem. Our teacher just mentioned the chain rule fast in the end of a lecture. My textbook doesnt explain it very thoroughly either.

All I've gotten so far is:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cdot 2ax + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} \cdot -xe^{-1/2x^2}$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cdot 2y + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} \cdot 0$

Substitution:

$y\cdot (\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cdot 2ax + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} \cdot -xe^{-1/2x^2}) + x \cdot (\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} \cdot 2y) = xyf(x,y)$

$2a\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} - e^{-1/2x^2}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} + 2\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} = f(x,y)$

Now I have no clue where to go from here. I've looked at similar examples from the book and online but they all seem so different that i cant really apply it to my problem. I feel really stupid right now.

Any help is greatly appreciated

[image: Here is an Image of the problem]

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm not sure what you mean by the first formula. Can i really compute $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ that way? (Actually I'm not following you at all ^^)

Comment: Sorry, I made a really careless mistake. I am not sure how they intend for you to do this. I know how I would do it but it doesn't really use just calc 3 machinery.

Comment: OK, I see what they want you to do, finally. Starting from what you did, take $a=-1$ to kill the $f_u$ terms and then notice that you are left with $-v f_v = f$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \left ( v f \right ) = 0$. You should be able to proceed from here, I think.

Comment: Thx Ian, that was very helpful!